# QTextEdit::cursorPositionChanged() -> synchronization font style with QComboBox and buttons

Tags: c++, qt, fonts, qtextedit, qtextcursor

I got a problem. I'm typing a text with Font Size 15: "Hello". Then I'm typing a text with Font Size 20: "World". When I change position of the cursor back to first line, my font size will change from 20 to 15. But my QComboBox is still shows "20". How to do font style synchronization with QComboBox and buttons (Bold, Italics, Underline)?

https://thepasteb.in/p/Lghpcmp0oGM1mUW

Code:

```
#include "notepadwindow.h"
#include "ui_notepadwindow.h"
#include <QFileDialog>
#include <QComboBox>

NotepadWindow::NotepadWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::NotepadWindow)

{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    ui->actionBold->setCheckable(true);
    ui->actionItalics->setCheckable(true);
    ui->actionUnderline->setCheckable(true);
    ui->actionLeft->setCheckable(true);
    ui->actionRight->setCheckable(true);
    ui->actionCenter->setCheckable(true);
    ui->actionJustify->setCheckable(true);
    this->setCentralWidget(ui->textEdit); // Wyśrodkuj Pole tekstowe
    QComboBox* myComboBox = new QComboBox;
    ui->mainToolBar->addWidget(myComboBox);
    for (int i = 1; i < 102; i += 2) {
      myComboBox->addItem(QString::number(i));
    }
    myComboBox->setCurrentText("11");
    ui->textEdit->setFontPointSize(11);
    ui->actionLeft->setChecked(true);
    ui->actionRight->setChecked(false);
    ui->actionCenter->setChecked(false);
    ui->actionJustify->setChecked(false);
    QObject::connect(myComboBox, SIGNAL(currentTextChanged(QString)), this, SLOT(onFontSizeChanged(QString)));
    connect(ui->textEdit, SIGNAL(QTextEdit::cursorPositionChanged()), this, SLOT());


}


NotepadWindow::~NotepadWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}



void NotepadWindow::openfile(QString textfile)
{
        QFile sFile(textfile);
        if(sFile.open(QFile::ReadOnly | QFile::Text)) // Jeśli plik jest otwarty
        {
            mFilename = textfile;
            QTextStream in(&sFile);
            in.setCodec("UTF-8"); // Ustaw kodowania znaków na UTF-8
            QString text = in.readAll();
            sFile.close();
            ui->textEdit->setHtml(text);
        }
}

void NotepadWindow::onFontSizeChanged(QString selected)
{
    ui->textEdit->setFontPointSize(selected.toInt());
}

void NotepadWindow::on_actionUndo_triggered()
{
    ui->textEdit->undo();
}

void NotepadWindow::on_actionRedo_triggered()
{
    ui->textEdit->redo();
}

void NotepadWindow::on_actionCut_triggered()
{
    ui->textEdit->cut();
}

void NotepadWindow::on_actionCopy_triggered()
{
    ui->textEdit->copy();
}

void NotepadWindow::on_actionPaste_triggered()
{
    ui->textEdit->paste();
}

void NotepadWindow::on_actionNew_triggered()
{
    mFilename = "";
    ui->textEdit->setPlainText("");
}

void NotepadWindow::on_actionOpen_triggered()
{
    QString file = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this, "open"); // Otwórz okienko wyboru plików
    if(!file.isEmpty())        // Jeśli plik nie jest pusty
    {
        QFile sFile(file);
        if(sFile.open(QFile::ReadOnly | QFile::Text)) // Jeśli plik jest otwarty
        {
            mFilename = file;
            QTextStream in(&sFile);
            in.setCodec("UTF-8"); // Ustaw kodowania znaków na UTF-8
            QString text = in.readAll();
            sFile.close();
            ui->textEdit->setHtml(text);
        }
    }
}

void NotepadWindow::on_actionSave_triggered()
{
    QFile sFile(mFilename);
    if(sFile.open(QFile::WriteOnly | QFile::Text)) // Jeśli plik jest otwarty
    {
        QTextStream out(&sFile);
        out << ui->textEdit->toHtml();
        out.setCodec("UTF-8"); // Ustaw kodowania znaków na UTF-8
        sFile.flush();
        sFile.close();

    }
    else if(!sFile.open(QFile::WriteOnly | QFile::Text)) on_actionSave_as_triggered();
}

void NotepadWindow::on_actionSave_as_triggered()
{
    QString file = QFileDialog::getSaveFileName(this,  tr("Text File"), "", tr("Text files (*.txt)"));
    if(!file.isEmpty())
    {
        mFilename = file;
        on_actionSave_triggered();
    }
}




void NotepadWindow::on_actionBold_triggered(bool checked)
{
    if(checked)
    {
        ui->textEdit->setFontWeight(QFont::Bold);
    }
    if(!checked)
    {
        ui->textEdit->setFontWeight(QFont::Normal);
    }

}

void NotepadWindow::on_actionItalics_triggered(bool checked)
{
    if(checked)
    {
        ui->textEdit->setFontItalic(1);
    }
    if(!checked)
    {
        ui->textEdit->setFontItalic(0);
    }

}

void NotepadWindow::on_actionUnderline_triggered(bool checked)
{
    if(checked)
    {
        ui->textEdit->setFontUnderline(1);
    }
    if(!checked)
    {
        ui->textEdit->setFontUnderline(0);
    }

}

void NotepadWindow::on_actionLeft_triggered()
{
    ui->textEdit->setAlignment(Qt::AlignLeft);
    ui->actionLeft->setChecked(true);
    ui->actionRight->setChecked(false);
    ui->actionCenter->setChecked(false);
    ui->actionJustify->setChecked(false);
}

void NotepadWindow::on_actionCenter_triggered()
{
    ui->textEdit->setAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);
    ui->actionLeft->setChecked(false);
    ui->actionRight->setChecked(false);
    ui->actionCenter->setChecked(true);
    ui->actionJustify->setChecked(false);
}

void NotepadWindow::on_actionRight_triggered()
{
    ui->textEdit->setAlignment(Qt::AlignRight);
    ui->actionLeft->setChecked(false);
    ui->actionRight->setChecked(true);
    ui->actionCenter->setChecked(false);
    ui->actionJustify->setChecked(false);
}

void NotepadWindow::on_actionJustify_triggered()
{
    ui->textEdit->setAlignment(Qt::AlignJustify);
    ui->actionLeft->setChecked(false);
    ui->actionRight->setChecked(false);
    ui->actionCenter->setChecked(false);
    ui->actionJustify->setChecked(true);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like said on your last comment, you have the same problem with alignement.

I think the main thing to do in your software is to "**update**" UI informations like font-size, alignement, bold and so one when it is different.
That's exactly what Microsoft Word and others writer do.

The main idea is the same that before but in the more common way:

1. Trigger the [currentCharFormatChanged(const QTextCharFormat &f)](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextedit.html#currentCharFormatChanged) **signal** to get informations about the actual text (bold, italic pointSize aso..)
2. Update UI informations about last informations (If text it is bold, check the bold button aso..)

Because QTextCharFormat gives only informations about characters and not alignment, you have to get `ui->textEdit->alignment()` to get alignment informations

So in parallel, for alignment you do the same:

1. Trigger the cursorPositionChanged() signal
2. Update UI alignment buttons (If alignment is left, check the "left alignment" button, if center, check the center one aso..)

Here is your code:

notepadwindow.h : https://pastebin.com/8b5UqnZF

notepadwindow.cpp: https://pastebin.com/ufJPM2Yj

---

## Learn to read the Doc or begin with easier things

**I am maybe wrong but with what I saw, it seems that you don't really know what you are doing.**

I mean, I searched into the doc to find the responses you need. I didn't find them directly, I had to try and to understand how it worked and the only thing I used was the doc. It appears that you asked multiple times people to help you on forums and that is what bring me to this conclusion.

I know that you are certainly a beginner, and that maybe you think that searching on the doc is a waste of time or that you don't understand anything on it, but if you want to progress in programming, you have to read documentations (even if you don't understand anything on it) and try easy things at the beginning to understand what you are doing.

#### Don't take it like a reproach but more like an advice: Read the documentation if you know what you do, if not, begin with easier things.

Comment: You are the best! :D

Answer (score 0):

### **Edited 2 (16.12.2017):**

[image]

I said you on the last edit of this post what you have to change and you said it didn't work.

I took all your code and made the change I said and it works perfectly for me.

https://pastebin.com/raw/Y38eLYbK

---

### **Edited (15.12.2017):**

So, I maybe understood what is going on with your code:

[By setFontPointSize(), your are changing the current format size.](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextedit.html#setFontPointSize) that is represented with a [QTextCharFormat](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextcharformat.html).

So basically you have this:
[image]

When you put your cursor on "Hello", it takes the QTextCharFormat associated with Hello (fontPoinzeSize that equals 15). So your top right font size has no effect on it.

What you have to do is to change the current QTextCharFormat with the size you have on the top right when you place your cursor on other position like this:

```
/*  In your .h */
class NotepadWindow{

    /* ... */

    private:
        int m_actualPointSize;
}


/** In your cpp */
NotepadWindow::NotepadWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::NotepadWindow)

{
    /* ... */
    connect(ui->textEdit, SIGNAL(cursorPositionChanged()), this, SLOT(changeCursorPosPointSize()));
}

void NotepadWindow::onFontSizeChanged(QString selected)
{
    m_actualPointSize = selected.toInt();
    ui->textEdit->setFontPointSize(m_actualPointSize);
}

void NotepadWindow::changeCursorPosPointSize()
{
    QTextCharFormat format;
    format.setFontPointSize(m_actualPointSize); // Put the variable that is associated with 
    ui->textEdit->mergeCurrentCharFormat(format);
}
```

---

### **Old post:**

Maybe QTextEdit (ui->textEdit) is not updated and you maybe need to call the update function.

Try it like this:

```
void NotepadWindow::onFontSizeChanged(QString selected)
{
    ui->textEdit->setFontPointSize(selected.toInt());
    ui->textEdit->update(); // Or ->repaint();
}
```

If it doesn't work, can you please tell us what is the method called by this line:

```
connect(ui->textEdit, SIGNAL(QTextEdit::cursorPositionChanged()), this, SLOT());
```

because SLOT() is pointing to any method.

Comment: I see white letters after changing font size by QComboBox. https://thepasteb.in/p/qjhPcEA5zP1EBip

Comment: Yeah that's because you don't have to put QTextEdit:: before the SIGNAL method.

`connect(ui->textEdit, SIGNAL(cursorPositionChanged()), this, SLOT(changeCursorPosPointSize()));`

Try with it like this

Comment: Make a zip/gzip with all your source code and upload it I could fix it more easily

Comment: Look my post, I edited it 2 times, you have to read it again please because you didn't read what I wrote the second time and it works perfectly with what I said.

Comment: I just put a thepastebin link. Don't hesitate to try it and say if it works (with validation please). Ty

Comment: Hmm, I I had to overlook something. I have read your edited post and it didin't work for me. The pastebin you send is empty.

Comment: I edited it again: https://pastebin.com/raw/Y38eLYbK (Don't know why it disappeared)

Comment: Could you tell me if it is ok now ? And if yes make the subject as completed (vote)

Comment: Yes, now is ok with QComboBox, but there is the same problem with bold, italics, underline and text alignment :/

Comment: I still have no idea how to do with alignment :/

Comment: What do you mean by alignment ?